# Can we save image in cookie via in php. If yes then how

Tags: php

Can we save image in cookie via in php. If yes then h

Comment: Your question is very unclear... can you elaborate ... ? What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: You can't save an image as a cookie, but you could save the path to the picture. (You MAY be able to do it, but you really don't want to). Not sure what maxsize of the cookie-value is, but I am 99.9% sure it is too short to store image-information.

Comment: Around 4 kb in IE if i can recall it.

Comment: You can save the path to the image for sure, but what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Encode the image as a string, for example using base64, and save the resulting string in cookie. It will only work for small images (max cookie size is 4kb).